# How to duplicate branch

Tags: git, merge, branch

I have two branches.  'master' and 'testing'.

```
                ___testing____  
               /
------master--------
```

I want to continue with the testing branch to add features, but before that, I need to merge the testing branch to master. I want to create a third branch called 'testing2' that is exactly the same as 'testing', but comes from the 'master' branch instead of being a branch off of 'testing'.

```
                   _____testing___
                  /
---------master----------
                  \____testing2____
```

As an alternative, I know I can merge the 'testing' branch to 'master' and create two new branches and do my work that way,

```
                _____testing_____        ____newtest___
               /                 \      /                 
---master-------------------------------------------------
                                        \____continuetest_____
```

but is there not a way to simply duplicate the branch 'testing'?

Comment: Would `git branch testing2 testing` work for your case?

Answer (score 6):

If you have used other version control systems—especially Mercurial, which really is a lot like Git but with some key differences including this very one here—you might expect commits to remember which branch they were made on.

In Mercurial, they do.

In Git, they don't.

#### A branch name is nothing more than a label pointing to *one* commit

In Git, think of a branch name as a sort of yellow sticky note.  The note has the name of the branch on it, but it's just loosely attached to the commit itself:

```
<--o   <--branch
```

The commit has its own outgoing arrow, which points to the commit's *parent commit*.  This builds up a backwards chain of commits.  If we give each commit a single letter name and draw arrows saying who points to whom, we get:

```
A <- B <- C   <-- branch
```

Here `A` is the very first commit ever.  It has no parent—it can't have one, so it just doesn't.  `B` is the second commit, and its parent is `A`, so `B` *points to* `A`.  (Literally, `B` has `A`'s hash ID inside it, as part of `B` itself.)  Likewise, `C` points to `B`.  The name `branch` remembers the big ugly hash ID of commit `C`, so that we don't have to.

To make a *new* commit:

1. Git collects a *log message* from you.
2. Git writes out the *index* (aka staging area): whatever you have updated with `git add` is new, everything else is the same as before.
3. Git writes out a new commit.  The new commit's *parent* is the current commit (its hash ID).  The new commit's *log message* is the one you wrote; the author and committer of the new commit is you; and the saved *tree* (source code) for the new commit is the result of writing out the index.
4. This new commit has a new, unique hash ID, different from every other commit ever made.
5. **Here is the secret of branches:** Whatever branch you are on right now, Git *puts the new ID* into the branch name.  So now `branch` remembers the *new* commit `D` we just made:

   ```
   A <- B <- C <- D   <-- branch
   ```

   In effect, Git peels the sticky-note off the old commit and pastes it on the new one.

If you attach multiple names to *one* commit, and then make a new commit, Git only peels off *one* sticky-note.  So if you make a new name that points to `C`, and then make new commit `D`, only the *current* branch name moves to `D`, the old one stays with `C`:

```
A--B--C     <-- newname
       \
        D   <-- branch
```

#### You should now ask how Git knows which label is the *current* branch!

The answer is `HEAD`.  This is why, if you use `git log --decorate`, you will see things like:

```
commit e0688e9... (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
```

This tells me that Git believes the *current* branch is `master`, and that there are *three* names for the current commit `e0688e9...`: `master`, `origin/master`, and `origin/HEAD`.

Answer (score 2):

Branching from `testing` to create a `testing2` branch is equivalent to creating a branch from `master` that is the same as `testing`.

For example:

```
                              ___testing2__
                ___testing___/
               /
------master--------
```

is *logically* equivalent to:

```
                ___testing___
               /
------master--------
               \___testing2__
```

with the same changes in the `testing` and `testing2` branches. It may not show like that in the log/graph, but it is the same.

Think about it more like:

```
                X
               /
------master--------
```

where the commit at `X` has both branch labels of `testing` and `testing2`.

I've just created this structure to give a better view. When creating the `testing2` branch, you will get:

[image: starting point]

Once you've made some commits on each branch, you will get:

[image: after commits to branches]

Comment: So then if we merge 'testing' to 'master', 'testing2' is going to be from 'master' anyway, correct?

Comment: Yes, all of `testing` will then be in `master`, and some of `testing2` (the bits that came from `testing`) will be also.

Comment: But the specific things about testing2 will remain in testing2 and outside of master, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Merge with master then:

```
git checkout master
git branch testing2
git pull origin master
```

Comment: Wouldn't 'testing2' then have 'testing' as it's parent rather than 'master'?

Comment: @TheRedCameron: *branches* don't have parents (which is what adrianbanks is telling you as well). Only *commits* have parents. Commits are named by their hash IDs (`face0ff` and so on, usually unpronounceable and impossible to remember). So Git has tags and branch-names that remember those hash IDs *for* you. That's almost all they do: remember a hash ID.